# Unable to get Eclipse/PyDev via Help > Install New Software

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I add this as a repository:

```
http://pydev.org/updates/
```

This ends up getting redirected to:

```
to https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/4.5.5/content.xml
```

which is a bad link in that there is not a content.xml file. There is a content.jar file, though.

When I add:

```
http://pydev.org/updates/
```

to the **Work with** field, I get this error:

```
HTTP Server 'Service Unavailable': http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml
HTTP Server 'Service Unavailable': http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml
HttpComponents connection error response code 503.
```

When I enter:

```
http://pydev.org/updates/
```

into Chrome, it displays:

```
Nothing to see here (this is just a dummy link to be redirected to https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/4.5.5)
```

What's the issue here?

I've download the zip file and installed it, so I'm not stuck, but this way makes updates a little more work.

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

Comment: Hard to say, given that it seems to work for me... As a note, it doesn't really need content.xml (it can also get content.jar, which is there, although the message says that the last thing it tried wast content.xml and had that error) -- my guess is that it's some connectivity issue on your side (do you have some proxy in place?) or it was a temporary downtime issue.

Comment: It is automatically appending "content.xml", I'm not typing that in.

Comment: I know that (and I didn't imply otherwise), what I meant is that content.xml is its last try and the point where it gives the error and shows you the message, but it should've tried content.jar before content.xml (which should've been found).

Comment: It's not a temporary downtime issue, it's happened over several days now. It may be a connectivity issue (firewall/certs). That's what I'm looking into currently, e.g. maybe the browser and IDE use different ports. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: This was a firewall/cert issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just open 'Help > Install New Software'.

Enter

```
http://pydev.org/updates/
```

in the 'Work with' field and press Enter.

After a few moments the table should then be populated with the available installs:
[image: Install New Software Dialog]

Comment: Added more info to the question based on your input

Answer (score 0):

Open the following URL in Browser and paste it over there,

```
http://pydev.org/updates/
```

and you will find the following URL

```
https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/7.4.0
```

then Copy it and paste it in the following URL field in Eclipse.

Just open it via Eclipse **'Help > Install New Software'**

[image]
Then, **Next> Accept> Finish..**